# What does an empty string ("") for dependency version mean in an npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

I found this in a package.json's dependencies:

```
"example_package": "",
```

What does an empty string as a version number mean? Will it just install the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Empty string is equivalent to "*".
Ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json

Answer (score -1):

According to [`semver`](https://github.com/npm/node-semver), which is the library used by npm to parse version strings, an empty version string is invalid:

```
const semver = require('semver')

semver.valid('') // returns null
```

```
$ npm install semver
$ npx semver ''
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: But the dependency string here isn't meant to contain a version number, it's meant to contain a version range.